# can you please tell, how can develop a parameterized query for date in powershell?

Tags: powershell, mongoexport

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin\mongoexport.exe" -ArgumentList ' --db=rndDB --collection=Messages  --type=csv  --fields Name,Message,Address,Start_date,End_date -q "{"Start_date":{"$gte":{"$date":"2021-02-02T22:30:00.000Z"},"$lt":{"$date":"2021-02-03T22:30:00.000Z"} } }" --out C:\Collection\Date_r2.csv'

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, please update your question to detail what doesn't work and what the expected behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

To expand variables, they must be placed in double-quotes. I assume you need the other double-quotes, so you can escape them with backtick <kbd>`</kbd>:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin\mongoexport.exe" -ArgumentList (
    ' --db=rndDB' +
    ' --collection=Messages' +
    ' --type=csv' +
    ' --fields Name,Message,Address,Start_date,End_date' +
    "-q `"{`"Start_date`":{`"$gte`":{`"$date`":`"2021-02-02T22:30:00.000Z`"},`"$lt`":{`"$date`":`"2021-02-03T22:30:00.000Z`"} } }" +
    '--out C:\Collection\Date_r2.csv'
)
```

Or combine single-quoted strings:

```
'-q "{"Start_date":{"'+$gte+'":{"'+$date+'":"2021-02-02T22:30:00.000Z"},"'+$lt+'":{"'+$date+'":"2021-02-03T22:30:00.000Z"} } }"' +
```